# How to use existing Azure function token as credentials?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure linux function app with ActiveDirectory auth enabled.

I have an Azure static web app with ActiveDirectory auth enabled. It generates a token which I then pass as a Bearer token when I call a function. This works.

In the function body how can I use the authenticated user's info to create a "credential" to then read/write to storage and other resources? When I use `DefaultCredentials` the SDK doesn't detect the auth.

My (trimmed) function:

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
  // req.user is below

  await readFile(...)

  context.res = {
    status: 200,
    body: {
      apps
    }
  };
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

What `req.user` contains (so Azure authenticates successfully, trimmed):

```
{
  type: 'AppService',
  id: '...',
  username: '...@....com',
  identityProvider: 'aad',
  claimsPrincipalData: {
    auth_typ: 'aad',
    claims: [
      ...
    ],
    name_typ: '...',
    role_typ: '...'
  }
}
```

How I want to use the credentials to read from blob storage (trimmed):

```
const readFile = async (...) => {
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential()

  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    credential
  );

  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

  const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();

  ...
}
```

The error I get:

```
Exception: ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed.
CredentialUnavailableError: EnvironmentCredential is unavailable. No underlying credential could be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DefaultAzureCredential is going to work for you, take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-node-latest#defaultazurecredential

It checks environment variables (Azure Tenant, Subscription, etc), then Workload identity, Managed Identity, and the Azure CLIs for credentials. Your error "EnvironmentCredential is unavailable, no underlying credential" means you don't have any of those authentication methods set up on your function-- I don't think that auth method is able to see the req.user context.

Could this be what you need?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/@azure/identity_3.3.0/sdk/identity/identity/samples/AzureIdentityExamples.md#authenticating-a-user-account-with-auth-code-flow

Are there other values in req? You need to get your hands on the user's auth code, so I would look through the req to see if that is included anywhere (maybe req.code or req.state? Could be req.user.code?). Once you have that, you can use the example above to create a credential and initiate your storage client.